# Sample scene keep continuously saying not loaded and I hit the play button the play scene is frozen in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm a beginner in mobile dev; when I started everything were fine my bird could be launch whitout issue but after adding :

```
private void Update()
{
    if (transform.position.y > 10 || transform.position.y < -10
        || transform.position.x > 10 || transform.position.x < -10)
    {
        string currentSceneName = SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name;
        SceneManager.LoadScene(currentSceneName);
    }
}
```

to reload the scene when x and y go over 10 or - 10 the  sample scene started displaying SampleScene (not loaded) and the play scene is frozen this is the image [image]

when I remove the Update function it work well.

this is the whole script:

```
 using UnityEngine;
 using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class Bird : MonoBehaviour
{

    Vector3 _initialPosition;
    [SerializeField]private float _launchPower = 500;

   private void Awake()
    {
        _initialPosition = transform.position;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (transform.position.y > 10 || transform.position.y < -10
            || transform.position.x > 10 || transform.position.x < -10)
        {
            string currentSceneName = SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name;
            SceneManager.LoadScene(currentSceneName);
        }
    }

    private void OnMouseDown()
    {
        GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = Color.red;
    }

 
    private void OnMouseUp()
    {
        GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = Color.white;
        Vector2 directionToInitialPosition = _initialPosition - transform.position;
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(directionToInitialPosition * _launchPower);
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().gravityScale = 1;
    }

    private void OnMouseDrag()
    {
        Vector3 newPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        transform.position = new Vector3(newPosition.x, newPosition.y); 
    }
}
```

Comment: So if your bird is not in a square from -10,-10 to 10,10 it tries to load the scene every frame. Seems Like a bad idea

Comment: I see do you have a better idea?

Comment: Soudns like from the very beginning the bird is already outside of the defined boundaries => reloads the scene very frame -> no good ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Admittedly I'm not entirely certain if this is the correct fix, I thought what you were doing should work, as long as the bird is not restarting outside of those parameters.

But, as BugFinder says, maybe it is not best to attempt to reload a scene in Update(). So, what you could try is telling another "SceneManager" object to restart the scene instead, and then disable your Bird script, so that it does not attempt to load a scene while it is already trying to do so.

```
Bird
{
    Update()
    {
        if(BirdOutOfRange())
        {
            //might be better to broadcast this as event and 
            //have MySceneManager listen for it
            MySceneManager.ReloadScene(); //may be better practice, but also may be unnecessary
                                    

           //Disable Bird to stop any future attempts to reload scene
           this.enabled = false;
```

Comment: `SceneManager.LoadScene` finishes in the same frame it was called. It (re)loads the scene => all currently running scripts are destroyed => This won't make any difference ;)

Comment: I thought that would have been the case. And I now see you may have spotted the bug in your other comment. Occam's razor!

Comment: And thanks for editing my answer. Trying to insert "code" was wrecking my head. You seem to have a pretty decent rep :) what's the best action when an incorrect answer has been submitted, delete it, or leave it there for somebody else to learn from my mistake? :P

Comment: usually you can delete it ... in this case though it was accepted by OP (who knows for which reason ^^) so just leave it .. I just wanted to note that this actually shouldn't be the answer to the question in general ^^